# Combining number states in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am completely new to Redux and I'm attempting to combine two states that are number values (item prices) into one total price state.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import setPlanPriceReducer from "./setPlanPrice";
import setRepairPriceReducer from "./setRepairPrice";

const setTotalPriceReducer = combineReducers({
    setPlanPriceReducer,
    setRepairPriceReducer
})

export default setTotalPriceReducer;
```

I am successfully combining all other reducers into a root reducer for my store and I am able to render the two individual prices correctly where needed.

```
import setPlanPriceReducer from "./setPlanPrice";
import setRenewalReducer from "./setRenewal";
import setDiscountReducer from "./setDiscount";
import setPlanReducer from "./setPlan";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import setRepairPriceReducer from "./setRepairPrice";
import setTotalPriceReducer from "./setTotalPrice";

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    plan: setPlanReducer,
    planPrice: setPlanPriceReducer,
    renewal: setRenewalReducer,
    repairPrice: setRepairPriceReducer,
    discount: setDiscountReducer,
    totalPrice: setTotalPriceReducer
});

export default allReducers;
```

However, I need my state tree to have the totalPrice set to one number (combining the values of planPrice and repairPrice) instead of the current object format:

[image]

I have read the Redux documentation on combineReducers and "Beyond combineReducers" and I still cannot make sense of it. Can someone please provide direction?

Comment: [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) as you can read here, will not output one number but rather **both** provided reducers to be accessed via a new object structure. You need to reconsider first making one reducer out of `setPlanPriceReducer` and `setTotalPriceReducer `, then assigning this to `totalPrice`

Comment: This could be handled by a [selector](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data), or, since basic math computations are not expensive at all, calculated as and when required in the relevant consuming components. You don't want to have the same reducers in two places in your state.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I tried the selector approach in combination with react state hook. Calling a function with this wouldn't work for me though: 

`setTotalPrice({planPrice} + {repairPrice})`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd have to see more code for how you're implementing that, and it probably deserves its own question.